# How to Right click on element and save as text file in mozilla firefox using selenium in JAVA

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I tried this code but it throwing Exception...

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: POST
>   /session/35794864-fb23-4bcc-bbb2-d474936e6742/moveto did not match a
>   known command (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace
>   information) Command duration or timeout: 9 milliseconds

This is my code:

//temp is my webelement

```
action.moveToElement(temp); 
action.contextClick(temp).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this...

you have written code to move to element but, you didn't build and perform.

action.moveToElement(temp).build().perform();

action.contextClick(temp).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();

Comment: I tried for chrome browser, but it is just opening context menu of right click, but I am not able to select option from right click. 
And In background left click action taking place and I don't want that.